# Открытие web_app на весь экран

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

По стандарту открывается на половину экрана, пытался задать высоту и ширину - безуспешно. Ничего не смог найти об этом, есть ощущение, что решение очень банальное, но дойти до него не могу

```
demo = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
demo.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='demo',  web_app=WebAppInfo(url=U10)))
```

Comment: Возможно функция `expand` https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-mini-apps

Comment: Не понимаю, как пользоваться expand, это ведь используется для билда приложения, а у меня прямая ссылка на веб-сайт

Comment: Не могу найти в документации aiogram как развернуть приложение на весь экран без доступа к коду самого приложения. Вы имеете доступ к редактированию этого сайта?

Comment: Нет, доступа к редактированию сайта нет, увидел, как это работает в стороннем боте, он тоже не имеет никакого отношения к сайту

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понял вопроса,

есть вариант решения проблемы если под webapp ты имеешь в виду любой веб-сайт, не знаю удобно для тебя это или нет:
импортируем модуль мышки:

import mouse #импорт модуля

mouse.move(x,y)  # перемещение курсора , вместо x и y ставь координаты кнопки "свернуть в окно"
mouse.click("left") #клик в тех координатах которые мы указали выше

да , вариант не удобный , но надеюсь хоть этим помог

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).